# How to repeatedly use a Perl file in another Perl file

Tags: perl

I am doing the below steps:

- Read all the text files in a directory and store it in an array named *@files*
- Run a foreach loop on each text file.
  Extract the file name(stripping of .txt) using split operation and creating a folder of that particular filename.
  Rename that file to *Test.txt* (so as to work as input fo another perl executable)
  Executing  test.pl for each file by adding the line *require "test.pl";*

It works fine for only one file, but not any more.
Here is my code:

```
opendir DIR, ".";
my @files = grep {/\.txt/} readdir DIR;

foreach my $files (@files) {

    @fn = split '\.', $files;
    mkdir "$fn[0]" 
        or die "Unable to create $fn[0] directory <$!>\n";

    rename "$files", "Test.txt";
    require "test3.pl";

    rename "Test.txt", "$files";
    system "move $files $fn[0]";
}
```

Any help would be very grateful.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `require` function trys to be smart and load the code only if it isn't already loaded. Why is this great? (1.) We don't have C's preprocessor hell with conditional includes, and (2.) we save time.

To execute another perl script, we have a *variety* of possibilites. The one that you probably want, is `do`ing a script. The `do FILENAME` syntax is just like eval, except that your scope isn't visible to the `do`ne file.

You could also start another interpreter via `system "./test3.pl"`.

You could make `test3.pl` a module, e.g. with `package test3;`, and pack the contents into a `sub`. Instead of hardcoding a filename, you would probably pass the current filename as an argument. This is not only better coding practice, but allows you to scale your application more easily, e.g. going multithreaded.

Here is how I'd implement that snippet:

```
use test3; # load the file once

foreach my $file (glob "*.txt") {   # use `glob` to get a list of matching filenames

    (my $newdir) = $file =~ m/^ (.+) \.txt $/x;  # what you probably wanted
    mkdir $newdir 
        or die "Unable to create $newdir directory <$!>\n";

    test3::the_sub($file); # do the action on $file, without renaming circus.
    system "move $file $newdir"; # rather use File::Copy
}
```

Interesting side points:

`glob` is great, works just as in the shell.

Always use `my` for variables, unless you have a really good reason.

I further assume that the file `text.en.txt` should not create the directory `text`, but `text.en`, and that the file `.txt` does not exist.

Whether this does or doesn't work also depends on the script you are calling.

Comment: Of course, the utopian implementation assumes that the OP has control over the contents of test3.pl. +1 for `system`

Comment: Salute to you for system("perl test3.pl") :-D My program works fine now! And Since I dont know how to create a package and use the"use test3" statements,next step for me will be modifying my program as you suggested to avoid the renaming circus.

Answer (score 0):

Use `do` instead of `require`. `require` only loads and runs the file once.